# How to crop a large image using Jcrop by resizing it?

Tags: jquery, html, jcrop

I am trying to crop a large image using Jcrop by setting its height and width attributes customized.I have tried many options in Jcrop, but nothing seems to work. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="FileUpload1" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif" />
<br />
<br />
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img id="Image1" src="" alt="" style="display: none; height:600px; width:600px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <canvas id="canvas" height="5" width="5"></canvas>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnCrop" value="Crop" style="display: none" />
<input type="hidden" name="imgX1" id="imgX1" />
<input type="hidden" name="imgY1" id="imgY1" />
<input type="hidden" name="imgWidth" id="imgWidth" />
<input type="hidden" name="imgHeight" id="imgHeight" />
<input type="hidden" name="imgCropped" id="imgCropped" />
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).delegate('#cover-image','change', function(e){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#Image1').show();
            $('#Image1').attr("src", e.target.result);
            $('#Image1').Jcrop({
                setSelect: [ 0,0,600,180 ],
                aspectRatio: 10/3,
                boxWidth: 600,
                boxHeight: 600,
                trueSize: [600, 600],
                onChange: SetCoordinates,
                onSelect: SetCoordinates
            });
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);      
    });

    $('#btnCrop').click(function () {
        var x1 = $('#imgX1').val();
        var y1 = $('#imgY1').val();
        var width = $('#imgWidth').val();
        var height = $('#imgHeight').val();
        var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            canvas.height = 180;
            canvas.width = 600;
            context.drawImage(img, x1, y1, width, height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            $('#imgCropped').val(canvas.toDataURL());
            $('#btnCrop').hide();
        };
        img.src = $('#Image1').attr("src");
    });
});

function SetCoordinates(c) {
    $('#imgX1').val(c.x);
    $('#imgY1').val(c.y);
    $('#imgWidth').val(c.w);
    $('#imgHeight').val(c.h);
    $('#btnCrop').show();
    $('#save-cropped-image, #delete-image').hide();
};
```

I am trying to crop a large image fit in a div which is shorter than image, so the image get compressed in it. But when I crop this image, its not returning me the correct co-ordinates and correct image is not generating in the canvas.

I am stuck off from 4hrs.Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Please check http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html

Comment: I am already see this documentation. But does not found perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Get original size of image and then crop.

```
$(document).delegate('#cover-image','change', function(e){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#Image1').attr("src", e.target.result);
                var $img = $("#Image1");
                $img.hide().removeClass("image12");
                var w = $img.width();
                var h = $img.height();
                $('#Image1').Jcrop({
                    trueSize: [w, h],
                    onChange: SetCoordinates,
                    onSelect: SetCoordinates
                });
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);      
        });

<style type="text/css">
.image12{
   height:600px; 
   width:600px;
}
</style>

<img id="Image1" class="image12" src="" alt="" style="display: none; " />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here this is s small trick to crop a div... put the div you want to crop inside another div.. set overflow of outer div to hidden them simply shift the inner div as you want to crop it using margin_left,right,top,down attributes...

Simple :)